# Testing if a file uploads sucessfully in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, functional-testing

I'm running Rails 3.2.13.

In one of my controllers, the application processes a form by which the users sends a file.
The application analyses the file and saves it OR NOT, depending on the analysis.

I want to write a functional test which tests that the correct file gets saved, and that the wrong file doesn't get saved.

I'm loading the file from test/fixtures/files, like this:

```
resource_file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.
    join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'f1.jpg'))
```

When running the test, where does this file gets saved?

Comment: It wasn't an issue with the location. While testing, it seems that the files are stored (or simulated to be stored) in the 'assets' location. I forgotted to add 'app' when joining the name, like File.join('app', 'assets'...)

Answer (score 0):

/spec/support/fixture_file.rb

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
def fixture_file(filename, extension)
  fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', filename), extension)
end
```

/spec/factories/offers.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :offer do
    large_picture { fixture_file("ostrov.jpg", "image/jpeg") }
  end
end
```

P.S It also works for TestUnit